# How do I change the starting screen size in Cocos2d-x 3.1 for Mac target?

Tags: macos, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

My app is supposed to run in portrait.  For iOS I specify this in the plist file.  For android it's in the Manifest.

When I try to run a Mac app it always launches in landscape, even though it's supposed to be in portrait.

I've tried to find the MainMenu.xib file specified in the Mac plist via XCode search, but in a 3.1 project, there wasn't one able to be found.  I also tried looking through the Mac specific files under platform->mac but didn't see anything related to screen sizes.

**Edit update:**

In addition to @GameDeveloper answer, I made the following changes:

```
if( !glView) {
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_MAC)
    glView = GLView::createWithRect("MyApp", Rect(0,0, 640, 960));
#else
    glView = GLView::create("MyApp");
#endif
}
```

It should be noted that the supplied rect is ideally your design size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no xib or nib.

in v 3.0

in `main.cpp` you should have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AppDelegate app;
    EGLView eglView;
    eglView.init("Hello World",900,640);
    return Application::getInstance()->run();
}
```

Change the 900 and the 640 values -> `width, height`

in v3.1

in `AppDelegate.cpp` you should edit `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to add `glview->setFrameSize(900, 640);` Where the 900 and 640 are your `width` and `height`

```
// initialize director
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
if(!glview) {
    glview = GLView::create("My Game");
    glview->setFrameSize(900, 640);
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

You probably want to make sure you only adjust this when running on MAC

Comment: In my main.cpp, there is only first and last lines, the EGLView lines are missing.  Am I supposed to add them?

Comment: See edits above.  Not sure if this is the right way to do it.  I will cross post on the Cocos forums.

Answer (score 2):

As of cocos2d-x version 3.4 (the current latest version), the syntax seems to have changed slightly. Only change that seems to be needed to change the screen size for Mac is:

`in AppDelegate.cpp:`

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // initialize director
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
    if(!glview) {
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_MAC)
         glview = GLViewImpl::createWithRect("MyApp", Rect(0,0, 320, 480));
#else
        glview = GLViewImpl::create("My Game");
#endif
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
    }
```

Comment: That's a tiny Mac game!